Prediction Errors with Time Series Forecasting - LSTM
Review of the Time Series Prediction Code
In this project, we aim to predict consumption values using a Long Short-Term Memory (LSTM) model based on historical data. Below is a breakdown of the various components and processes involved in the code.

Data Loading and Preprocessing
The first step involves loading the dataset from an Excel file. The dataset is indexed by time, allowing us to maintain a chronological order of the data. Sorting the index ensures that the data is organized correctly for time series analysis.

Next, we apply feature scaling using the MinMaxScaler. This technique normalizes the data to a range between 0 and 1, which is crucial for training neural networks as it helps in faster convergence and improved performance.

Creating Input and Output Datasets
The function create_supervised_dataset is designed to transform the scaled data into a supervised learning format. This involves creating input-output pairs where:

Input (X) consists of sequences of data points over a defined length (in this case, 24 hours).
Output (Y) is the target value we want to predict, specifically the consumption value at the next time step.
This transformation is essential for training the LSTM model, as it allows the model to learn from historical sequences.

Splitting the Dataset
The dataset is divided into training, validation, and testing sets:

Training Set: 80% of the data is used for training the model.
Validation Set: 10% is reserved for validating the model's performance during training.
Testing Set: The remaining 10% is used to evaluate the model after training.
This split is crucial for assessing the model's ability to generalize to unseen data.

Model Structure
The model is built using a Sequential architecture from TensorFlow's Keras API. It consists of:

An LSTM layer with 128 units, which is responsible for capturing temporal dependencies in the data.
A Dense layer with 64 units and a ReLU activation function, which introduces non-linearity to the model.
A final Dense layer with a single unit, producing the predicted consumption value for the next time step.
The model is compiled with the Adam optimizer and Mean Squared Error (MSE) as the loss function, which is suitable for regression tasks.

Training and Validation
The model is trained using the training dataset, with validation performed on the validation set. Early stopping is employed to prevent overfitting, monitoring the validation loss and halting training if no improvement is observed for a specified number of epochs.

During training, the loss curves are plotted to visualize the model's performance over epochs, helping to identify potential issues such as overfitting or underfitting.

Making Predictions
The function predict_hourly_consumption is responsible for generating future consumption predictions. It utilizes the last observed data points to predict the next values iteratively. Each prediction is scaled back to the original range using the inverse transformation of the scaler.

The function returns a DataFrame with future dates and their corresponding predicted consumption values.

Issue with Predictions
A notable issue arises where the predicted consumption values occasionally fall below zero or exceed expected limits. This could indicate that the model is not adequately capturing the underlying patterns in the data or that the scaling process may inadvertently lead to unrealistic predictions.

# 5. Función para predecir la variable Consumo
def predecir_consumo_hora_a_hora(modelo, df, scaler, horas_a_predecir, ventana=24):
    datos_historicos = df.values
    datos_entrada = datos_historicos[-ventana:, :]  # Últimos datos de entrada

    # Escalar los datos de entrada
    entrada_escalada = scaler.transform(datos_entrada).reshape(1, ventana, -1)

    predicciones = []
    for _ in range(horas_a_predecir):
        # Predecir la siguiente hora
        prediccion_escalada = modelo.predict(entrada_escalada, verbose=0)[0, 0]  # Salida: (1,)

        # Desescalar la predicción
        prediccion = scaler.inverse_transform(
            np.hstack([prediccion_escalada.reshape(1, 1), np.zeros((1, df.shape[1] - 1))])
        )[0, 0]  # Solo desescala la primera columna ('Consumo')
        predicciones.append(prediccion)

        # Actualizar los datos de entrada
        nueva_fila = np.hstack([entrada_escalada[0, -1, 1:], prediccion_escalada]).reshape(1, -1)
        entrada_escalada = np.append(entrada_escalada[0, 1:], nueva_fila, axis=0).reshape(1, ventana, -1)

    # Crear DataFrame con las predicciones
    ultima_fecha = df.index[-1]
    fechas_futuras = [ultima_fecha + timedelta(hours=i + 1) for i in range(horas_a_predecir)]
    return pd.DataFrame({'Fecha': fechas_futuras, 'Consumo_Predicho': predicciones}).set_index('Fecha')

# 6. Predecir valores futuros
horas_a_predecir = 24  # Cambiar según necesidad
predicciones = predecir_consumo_hora_a_hora(modelo, df_scaled, scaler, horas_a_predecir)
print(predicciones)

I change the model structure several times and try with differents input-output features. But still, the error remains, the predicted values are inconsistent with the reality. The electrical power in megawatts can not be negative or higher than the expected load. What should I do?
